# Highcharts - Linking two separate bar graphs together

Tags: highcharts

I'm unsure if this is a feature Highcharts provides, but I would like to link two separate bar graphs together. I've created two seperate bar graphs with the goal to have them side by side in a div like the image shows below. At the moment my issue is that graph #2 on the right side's `7%` graph larger then the `12% and 19%` in graph #1 because it its determining the size based off of the entries in graph #2. Is it possible to link the two so that all values being shown on both graphs account for one another? Or configure one to have a similar outcome to the one below?

Here is a like to a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dr7z36qb/3/) example

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can synchronize y-axis extremes by using `setExtremes` method:

```
var yAxis1 = chart1.yAxis[0],
    yAxis2 = chart2.yAxis[0],
    yMin = yAxis1.min < yAxis2.min ? yAxis1.min : yAxis2.min,
    yMax = yAxis1.max > yAxis2.max ? yAxis1.max : yAxis2.max;

yAxis1.setExtremes(yMin, yMax, true, false);
yAxis2.setExtremes(yMin, yMax, true, false);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tmv540y2/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

---

Or create one chart with two y-axes linked to each other.

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ok8746eh/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.linkedTo